# mysql sum to output in flot chart

Tags: mysql, sql, flot

Am trying to output running total for two table entries vs date on flot/jquery chart.

Code so far is working ok to output line chart for both values on given date but am trying to show running total for each column on same graph.
Not sure if can use single mysql query using SUM(value) to achieve this ?? - Just can't get it to work.

```
<?php

$query=("SELECT hours, credits, entryDate FROM entry WHERE uid='1'");

$result = mysql_query($query);        

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $credits[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,($row['credits']));
    $hours[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,($row['hours']));
} ?>

</script>
var credits = <?php echo json_encode($credits);?>
var hours = <?php echo json_encode($hours);?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'total for each column'? If you use `SUM` you will have one result (sum) and with that it is quite hard to have any chart.

Comment: _Running_ total for each column, not sure if this helps but this is what I'm trying to do - credits  hours  date
                         c1      h1      d1    
                         c2      h2      d2

giving two graphs :

GRAPH 1  [x1 = c1     y1=d1]      
         [x2 = c1+c2  y2=d2]

GRAPH 2  [x1=h1       y1=d1]
         [x2=h1+h2    y2=d2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest was to do it would be to just keep a running total in php, putting that out for each date as well:-

```
<?php

$query=("SELECT hours, credits, entryDate FROM entry WHERE uid='1' ORDER BY entryDate");

$result = mysql_query($query);        

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $runningtotalcredits += $row['credits'];
    $runningtotalhours += $row['hours'];
    $credits[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$row['credits']);
    $creditssofar[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$runningtotalcredits);
    $hours[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$row['hours']);
    $hourssofar[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$runningtotalhours);
} ?>

</script>
var credits = <?php echo json_encode($credits);?>
var hours = <?php echo json_encode($hours);?>
var creditssofar = <?php echo json_encode($creditssofar);?>
var hourssofar = <?php echo json_encode($hourssofar);?>
```

It should also be possible to do it in SQL using a correlated sub query but the efficiency might not be great:-

```
<?php

$query=("SELECT hours, 
                credits, 
                entryDate, 
                (SELECT SUM(hours) AS hourssofar FROM entry b WHERE uid='1' AND b.entryDate <= a.entryDate),
                (SELECT SUM(credits) AS creditssofar FROM entry c WHERE uid='1' AND c.entryDate <= a.entryDate)
        FROM entry a
        WHERE uid='1' 
        ORDER BY entryDate");

$result = mysql_query($query);        

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $credits[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$row['credits']);
    $creditssofar[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$row['creditssofar']);
    $hours[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$row['hours']);
    $hourssofar[] = array ( strtotime ($row['entryDate'])*1000,$row['hourssofar']);
} ?>

</script>
var credits = <?php echo json_encode($credits);?>
var hours = <?php echo json_encode($hours);?>
var creditssofar = <?php echo json_encode($creditssofar);?>
var hourssofar = <?php echo json_encode($hourssofar);?>
```

(neither tested)